# How do I set an image to full-width of the mobile screen without using the background image property in CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

I want to set every image on mobile to occupy the full width of the screen. I don’t think I’m targeting the correct div class though. Here is my URL: https://sportivepets.com/007-bond-dog-breed-match/
I’m focusing on the image of the English Foxhound on mobile. On desktop, it mustn’t occupy the full width of the screen as there is a sidebar.

Here is my css:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
.wp-block-image .size-large {
  height: 450px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-right: -20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;  
} 
}
```

I’m targeting the theme’s CSS in WordPress with custom CSS. Firstly, is the div class name correct, and secondly, is the CSS correct? The image doesn’t cover the full width of my mobile phone using the above CSS. I don’t want to use a background image property as each image will need to be set as a background image. I want to target the existing large image CSS div.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and see how to create a [MRE] with all of the code we need to see the problem, then [edit] your question to include the code here. A link to your website is not helpful to future users with similar questions, because once you fix the problem it no longer exists and the question no longer has all the information to make sense :)

Answer (score 0):

do you mean:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  img {
    width: 100%!important
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What your code says right now is that if a parent class is named `.wp-block-image` then if it has a child class which is named `.size-large` it will apply the CSS on the children in this case only on `.size-large`. So in your case this is what I would do:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
//This is for the English Foxhound image container
.figure.wp-block-image.size-large.is-resized {
  height: 450px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;  
  } 
}
```

I also see no reason for you to use the background styling-rules.
I would also use parent classes in order to get a better readability and easier targeting in your code.